# mysql query, multiple inserts, cross table update

Tags: mysql, insert

i have 2 tables 
faxhistory and temp

faxhistory is empty
temp is populated

temp every column type is varchar

i need to make a 1 query that inserts every row from temp
but before that, converts data (varchar to int, etc)

Comment: What kind of colums are there in temp?

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: faxhistory - id fax date time status_code status_text duration pages loops company_id
temp - faxnumber date time status_code status_text duration pages

Comment: i tried via cross table update 
http://www.electrictoolbox.com/article/mysql/cross-table-update/

Comment: You should have designed your 'faxhistory' table to be a identical to the 'temp'!

Comment: thats true but, the thing is, ive been given numerous reports in csv format where the column names or the number or column names differ, i could do that in php, but the volume is 50k+ of rows, that will be very inefficient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `cast('column' as decimal(p,s))` to convert your varchar fields to number.

Try the following:

```
select cast(t.'column1' as decimal(p,s)), cast(t.'column2' as decimal(p,s)), t.'columnN' 
into f.'column1', f.'column2', f.'columnN' 
from faxhistory f, temp t
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, have a cookie:

```
CREATE TABLE `faxhistory` (  <your create statement> )  COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci';
INSERT INTO `faxhistory` ( `id`, `fax`, `date`, `time`, `status_code`, `status_text`, `duration`, `pages`, `loops`, `company_id`) SELECT `id`, `fax`, `date`, `time`, `status_code`, `status_text`, `duration`, `pages`, `loops`, `company_id` FROM `temp`;
```

Above code only if your faxhistory is still empty! otherwise, use the following on any column and any set.

```
ALTER TABLE `faxhistory` CHANGE COLUMN `id` `id` INT NOT NULL;
```